# how to check output of particular component on webpage in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new on angular. I got issue regarding components. I have created a component with name test.

I got the right output when i run the code, but when i delete the  tag from app.component.html then i got blank web page as an output.

Here is the code of test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Here is the code of test.component.html

## test is working

Here is the code of app.component.html

```
<app-test></app-test>
```

Please correct me where am doing wrong. Is this necessary to declare every selector tag of every component in app.component.html (root html code)

Comment: I really don't understand this question and I read it several times

Comment: If you don't use your component in a template (or dynamically add it via a componentFactory), it's not used.  Thats the expected behavior.  I would strongly recommend running through the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial if you haven't already, it covers the basics of building an Angular app.  https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the component tag in app.component.html, you are telling the angular compiler to render that component on your web page, when you delete that tag '' then the compiler have nothing to render so it shows you blank page.

You are doing nothing wrong, you just have to decide what components you want to render on page.

And yes it is necessary to declare every selector tag of every component in not only app.component.html, but where ever you want it to render.

You can even use Angular routing to conditionally show components via routing. For reference: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

It is important to add selector () in app.component.html. If you want that components need to visible or not.

Just like if you define routes of the project then you need to add router-outlet in the main component.

Comment: Okay so you mean i have to declare the selector tag of every component in app.component.ts, right?

Comment: No we use <router-outlet> to render component in app.component.html

Comment: Yes, you have to declare this tag if you want to render this component.